# Is there a way to hide sqlalchemy output from jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook, pyodbc

I imported some SQL libraries to be used on jupyter notebook, the SQL Server Management Studio credential is a Window Authentication (i.e i do not need a password to use SQL SSMS).

Below is the code snippet and an image that shows the output.

```
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc


SERVER = 'SERVERNAME'
DATABASE = 'DATEBASENAME'
DRIVER = 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
USERNAME = 'MyUserName'
PASSWORD = ''

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@' + SERVER + '/' + DATABASE + '?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server')
connection = engine.connect()
%reload_ext sql

%sql mssql+pyodbc://@SERVERNAME/DATABASENAME?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server&trusted_connection=yes

team_query = """
SQL_QUERY
"""

team = %sql $team_query
team = team.DataFrame()
```

[image]

How do i hide the output generated from the image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the cell magic function `%%capture --no-display`:

[image]